# How to identify PDF pages that contain highlighted text via command-line

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf, utilities, highlighting

Assume a pdf document that contains text highlights on pages 1, 3 and 14. Is there a Linux command-line tool (or a set of tools whose output can be piped to each other) that can report the page numbers of those pages that contain highlighted text? Something like:

```
$ sought_tool --list-pages-with-highlights doc.pdf
1 3 14
```

Comment: There are a number of ways you can highlight in PDF files, so any tool that exists may not succeed in catching all types. I’m not aware of any tool that does this. I’m also aware of many tools that interfere or removed (incorrectly) other highlighting or annotations when editing a pdf. So your mileage may vary.

Comment: @JamesRisner I understand that there is no one-size-fits-all solution for PDF highlights and would be happy to be recommended *any* tool that returns page numbers for highlighted pages, even if it works sub-optimally.

Comment: I have used a ton of tools (mtools, cpdf, qpdf, pdktk, etc.) I don't recall any of them doing much with highlighted text. So I can't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The nifty little Python library [pdfannots](https://github.com/0xabu/pdfannots) has exactly the desired capability.

```
$ pdfannots doc.pdf
```

If combined with `grep` and `awk` it can produce the desired result.

```
$ pdfannots doc.pdf | \
  grep "* Page #" | \
  awk -F':' '{print $1}' | \
  awk -F'#' '{print $2}' | \
  sort -u -n | \
  paste -s -d ' '
1 3 14
```

Comment: Excellent answer!